# Light switch to switch/outlet combo

Tags: switch, receptacle

I have an older house and want to change a light switch to a switch/outlet combo. The current switch has two wires only in the box. The new combo has a ground (green), and two lines on one side. The other side has a load and neutral (white). 
My question is, if this combo can be hooked up with the existing setup, how can it be done?

Comment: Are you ready to pull new wires through the walls?

Comment: Yes, can you pull new wiring for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if this combo can be hooked up with the existing setup,..?

The answer to this question is **NO**

The box only contains a source or hot leg down to the switch and a switch leg back to the light fixtures. You will need to install a neutral and a ground into the box. Updated NEC now requires neutrals to be installed in boxes unfortunately your dwelling did not.

Hope this helped.